# where do I install axios in nativescript-vue app?

Tags: vue.js, npm, axios, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I have two package.json files. One at the root of my project and another one in the app directoty(where the vue files are) I'm confused about which one I should use for installing axios. I would also like to know what purpose do each of these serve, which packages should be installed to which one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add at the package.json at the root level. The package.json at the `root` is used to define the dependencies of the template, to persist some project specific information e.g. version, scripts, hooks etc.

The package.json in the app folder serves several other purposes:

Most important - this package.json(inside app one)  defines the entry point of the application (e.g `"main": "main.js"` or  `"main": "main.ns.js"`, ). At runtime this value is read and application is started from this point.

Here is an example of package.json inside `app` folder.

```
{
  "android": {
    "v8Flags": "--expose_gc"
  },
  "main": "main.ns.js",
  "name": "migration-ng",
  "version": "4.1.0"
}
```

Comment: excuse me, how do I ass at the package.json ate? :))

Comment: When you run 'npm install axios --save', it aill automatically add into your package.json

Comment: you are not getting it:D

Comment: anyway, can you elaborate a little more, so I should install my devDeps to the package.json in the app dir?

Comment: You have to install dependencies e.g. `"nativescript-accordion": "^6.0.0-beta.2",
    "nativescript-angular": "~7.0.0",` and "devDependencies": {"typescript": "~3.1.1",} in your `root` folder package.json

Comment: Then what do you mean by:The package.json in the app folder serves several other purposes:

It defines the dependencies and devDependencies required to use the template - cli copies them to root's package.json during creation.

Answer (score 2):

Narendara is right install in package.json and use it like this

````
import axios from "axios/dist/axios";

axios.get(`domain`).then(response => {});```
````

Answer (score 0):

package.json file at root lvl just add

"axios": "^0.18.0",